# Click event on <a> element not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML is structured as below. I would like to give the clicked `<a>` element the class "active".

Although the debugger stops on the `click()` line, the code within the function is not being triggered.

```js
$('#dropdownRow > div > a').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#dropdownRow a.active').removeClass('active');
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="dropdownRow">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <a href="/xxx/">XXX</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <a href="/yyy/">YYY</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <a href="/zzz/">ZZZ</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery code at? above or below the HTML?

Comment: [Works perfectly as is](https://jsfiddle.net/65o26vvy/). FYI, the `hasClass()` test is unnecessary.

Comment: I converted your code to a snippet. As you can see it works fine. Check to ensure that you're running your code when the DOM is ready, ie. in a ready handler or placed just before `</body>`

Comment: i think it is working in the snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you do not have the jQuery firing at the right time. I suggest wrapping it in a $(document).ready

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Add your code
  $('#dropdownRow > div > a').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#dropdownRow a.active').removeClass('active');
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
      $this.addClass('active');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  // End code 
});
```